# Changing your django model when you share the DB with other programmers?

Tags: database, django

We are currently sharing a DB (for testing purposes).

- I change model code, and applies the change (south migration) to the DB. but many times I  have broken stuff and unable to commit at this point.
- At the same time, my teammates find their DB schema defined in their code and actual DB's schema is different.

So how do people handle this scenario?

Should we separate DB while we update modeling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our case, each programmer has local database instance running for development purposes. We also have **staging** server for testing purposes before deploying to **production** server.